# Average of specific pixels

Tags: arcmap, average

[image]I have a raster of estimated soil moisture values and 30 points of field measurements.

I wanted to correlate the measured and estimated values using scatterplot but the result in not good. There might have been errors while field measurements and my map has a high resolution of 10cm, so I decided to calculate an average of 10 pixels in each direction for each point so I have an average value of 1m for each point which hopefully will increase the result accuracy.

How can I calculate just an average of specific pixels in ArcMap 10? I know about zonal statistics but here I dont have another raster dataset. I have to chose the pixels I need around each point.

Comment: Thanks. But by using Extract by points, I will get value of my raster only for that point. I need an average of some specific cells around that point. I attach a picture of my map and the desired area that I want the average from. Thanks

Comment: You can use both raster and feature class as zone layer in [zonal statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm): "The zones can be defined by an integer raster or a feature layer." Buffer Points and use output as zones

Answer (score 1):

create a buffer around each point then use spatial analyst with the buffers. If you want a square (but I think that a circle is better anyway), then you can use "minimum bounding rectangle" around your circle. On the other hand, your field moisture values seem very heterogeneous, so taking the average would not be very useful. I would rather try to make sure that my raster is correctly georeference and that my points are precisely geolocated (you'll need a DGPS for that)